# Write to excel using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache

Earlier I was using SAX parser for export to excel. Now I am not able to get data using Apache POI, Any suggestion??? 
This String in XML contains all the data which I retrieved through farpoint grid tech and set in the form in action class.

```
private void parseXML(String inXML) {
    /* // get a factory
    SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    try {
        // get a new instance of parser
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();

        // parse the file
        sp.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(inXML)), this);    
    } catch (IOException ie) {          
}*/
```

Now I am using this.

```
 HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
 HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sample sheet");
 short rowNum = 0;
 short colNum = 0;

 Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
 Cell cell = row.createCell(colNum);
 cell.setCellValue(inXML);

 **/* Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
 while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
     Row row = rowIterator.next();

     //For each row, iterate through each columns
     Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
     while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {                       
         Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
         cell.setCellValue(inXML);

         switch(cell.getCellType()) {
             case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                 System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "\t\t");
                 break;
             case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                 System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t\t");
                 break;
             case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                 System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t");
                 break;
         }
     }*/**

     try {
         FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Excel.xls"));
         workbook.write(out);
         out.close();                                     
     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }    
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?  You say you were using SAX to parse XML and now you're trying to use POI to create spreadsheet?  What does one have to do with the other?  From what you posted it looks like you are trying to stuff XML into a cell (based solely on the name of the variable: inXML).   And you don't describe the problem. Are you not able to create the spreadsheet?  Are you getting an exception? Does the spreadsheet contain the wrong data?  You've not provided enough info for anyone to help.

Comment: yeah as u said i'm trying to stuff xml in to cell, no exception or error is coming , prblm is spreadsheet is created bt its coming as no data(blank).

Answer (score 0):

This program (which is what you posted with added imports, without the comment block, with a literal string instead of the variable `inXML` and with the path removed from the output file):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;

public class Main {
    public Main() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sample sheet");
        short rowNum = 0;
        short colNum = 0;

        HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
        Cell cell = row.createCell(colNum);
        cell.setCellValue("<data>test data</data>");

        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("Excel.xls"));
            workbook.write(out);
            out.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Produced exactly what you would expect:  A spreadsheet with `<data>test data</data>` in cell A1.

Perhaps cell A1 in your spreadsheet is blank because `inXML` really is blank.